# Fast Android Networking cookies issue

Tags: android, android-networking

Am using [Fast Android Networking](https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking) in my Android project, and I want to use Cookies within it. When I setup the library without a Cookies class, the requests are OK and work smoothly, but when I add a custom Cookies handler, requests suddenly stop working, without throwing any error, or doing anything else.

What could be the issue? The code am using is as below:

```
CookieJar cookieJar = new CookieJar()
    {
        @Override
        public void saveFromResponse(HttpUrl url, List<Cookie> cookies)
        {
            appCtx.setCookies(url.host(), cookies); //custom storage based on SharedPrefs
        }

        @Override
        public List<Cookie> loadForRequest(HttpUrl url)
        {
            List<Cookie> cookieList = appCtx.getCookies(url.host());
            return cookieList;
        }
    };

//if I use the below, the client hangs without doing anything
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
    .cookieJar(cookieJar)
    .build();
AndroidNetworking.initialize(ctx, httpClient);

//if I skip the above and simply apply the below, requests go through smoothly. 
// Note, am only using one at a time, and commenting out the other
AndroidNetworking.initialize(ctx);

//then continue as usual
AndroidNetworking.setParserFactory(new JacksonParserFactory());
... //other code
```